# First paint time in Python (may be using Selenium or without it)?

Tags: python, selenium, paint, pageload

I want to find the time whatever (an object, image, text, link, DB or anything) loads first in a requested website using Python and Selenium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout `performance.timing`, it's JavaScript and comes default in your browser. You have a lot of options to display, like:

- navigationStart
- connectStart
- connectEnd
- domLoading
- domInteractive
- domComplete

Just go to your console window in your browser and type `performance.timing`. Might be of use to you.

If you find something you can use, you can use selenium to execute the JavaScript inside the browser using `execute_script`:

```
driver.execute_script(‘return performance.timing.domComplete’)
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help! If my answer answered your question, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: _Thanks_ @Marcel